# Convert Combobox item to char pointer

Tags: winforms, combobox, c++-cli

I'm working on winforms VC++.

I got selected item of combobox by:

```
String ^getSelectedFromCmbobox(){   

        String ^selected = this->combobox->SelectedItem->ToString();
        return selected;
    }
```

in MyForm.h file. I want to get seleceted item's name and concat it with another string("\\.\"), and use it as a `char *` parameter.

How can I do that?

Since it contains ^ sign it's hard to search in Google, excuse me if it is duplicate.

Comment: This is not C++, it is managed C++

Comment: Yes, I know it. Isn't there anyway to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way will be to use `StringToHGlobalAnsi` wich copies the contents of a managed String into unmanaged memory. Here the msdn link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi(v=vs.110).aspx.

Alsom, you have .Net method [String::Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat(v=vs.110).aspx) for concatenate String objects.